# Flutter - InteractiveViewer doesn't show top/bottom of Listview when panEnabled = true

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

The Listview  with the wrapped InteractiveViewer scrolls perfectly, except while in panned mode.

```
return InteractiveViewer(
              panEnabled: true,
              boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              minScale: 0.5,
              maxScale: 4,
              child: ListView(children: _childrenWidgets,)
       );
```

The Listview doesn't scroll all the way to the top/bottom when "pinch-to-zoom" (aka panning) occurs.
Thus, the panned content is hidden when the listview is already scrolled to the top/bottom.
But if I pinch to zoom back to the normal zoom state, then it will show everything.

My question is:

How can I allow the ListView to keep scrolling to the top/bottom when panning occurs?

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a bug in InteractiveWidget.

Opened an issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68073

A workaround for now is to use Zoomable Widget library:
https://pub.dev/packages/zoom_widget

This worked for me:

```
Widget menu = Zoom(
              initZoom: 0.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 2,
              opacityScrollBars: 0.0,
              centerOnScale: true,
              height: HEIGHT_CONSTANT,
              doubleTapZoom: true,
              enableScroll: true,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(children: tabChildren,),)
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question at this point but in case someone comes looking for a solution to this the solution is to use NeverScrollablePhysics() in the ListView's physics property.

```
ListView(
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: _childrenWidgets,
  )
```